# How to check whether a number is divisible by another in Jinja Template (Django Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to check a simple condition in Jinja Template inside for loop in a web page whether a number is divisible by three or not. 
I have referred the following link
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/
(Note loop.index doesnt work for me forloop.counter does)

The code is

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>List of all Reference Ids</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        {% for master in  object_list %}
            {%  if forloop.counter divisibleby 3 %}
                 Do something
            {%endif%}
            <td> <a href="/data/{{ master.id }}"> {{ master.reference_id }} </a></td>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Tried various combinations such as below

```
        {%  if forloop.counter divisibleby 3 %}
        {%endif%}

        {%  if forloop.counter divisibleby(3 %}
        {%endif%}

        {%  if divisibleby(forloop.counter,3) %}
        {%endif%}

        {%  if divisibleby forloop.counter 3 %}
        {%endif%}

        {%  if forloop.counter%3==0 %}
        {%endif%}
```

But nothing works. I dont know where I am making the mistake. Please help me out guys I am stuck into this problem for quite long.

Comment: The [docs you linked to](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#tests) show you how to do it: `{% if loop.index is divisibleby 3 %}`. If `loop.index` does not work, but `forloop.counter` does, then Django is treating your template as a Django template, not a Jinja template. If you need help fixing this, then you need to post your view and `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: Try like this:
`{% if forloop.counter is divisibleby 3 %}` or 
`{% if forloop.counter is divisibleby(3) %}`.

Comment: I am still getting this error Unused 'is' at end of if expression.
for `{% if forloop.counter is divisibleby 3 %} or {% if forloop.counter is divisibleby(3) %}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template_string = """
{% for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] %}
  {% if loop.index %3 == 0%}3{%else%}0{%endif%}\n
{% endfor %}
"""

from jinja2 import Template

print Template(template_string).render()
```

although it sounds like you are using django Template not jinja ...

if this is DjangoTemplateLanguage then

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
```

should work (I think ... ) so in full here is the djangoTemplate equivelent that is runnable standalone

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.engine import Engine

from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(DEBUG=False)

template_string = """
{% for i in the_list %}
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}3{%else%}0{%endif%}\n
{% endfor %}
"""
print Template(template_string).render(Context({"the_list":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}))
```

Comment: It is still not working. I just started to learn django framework so I am also bit confused about templates. The tutorial that I followed claimed that it is a Jinja Template.

Comment: you have to specify it in the settings.py of your django project ... if you did not explicitly set it then you are using django template language (you might want `forloop.counter` instead of `forloop.counter0`